# Unable to grab some information displayed in a new tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python using requests module to fetch some information displayed upon filling in a form using this email `africk2@nd.edu`. The problem is when I hit the search button, I can see a new tab containing all the information I wish to grab. Moreover, I don't see any link in the `All` tab under `Network` section within chrome dev tools. So, I'm hopeless as to how I can get the information using requests module.

[website address](https://eds.nd.edu/search/index.shtml)

> Steps to populate the result manually:
>
> Put this email address `africk2@nd.edu` next to the inputbox of `Email address` and hit the `Search` button.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://eds.nd.edu/search/index.shtml"
post_url = "https://eds.nd.edu/cgi-bin/nd_ldap_search.pl"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('input[name]')}
payload['email'] = 'africk2@nd.edu'
del payload['clear']

resp = requests.post(post_url,data=payload)
print(resp.content)
```

The above script is a faulty approach. However, I can't find any idea to grab the information connected to that email.

P.S. I'm not after selenium-oriented solution.

Comment: I am curious as of why you are not looking for selenium? As you could run chrome headless and have a simple solution without even seeing the browser being used. Just wondering if none headless would be the reason..

Comment: Because I know already how to achieve the same using selenium. It is `driver.window_handles` what can do the trick. However, I don't know how to proceed with requests module in such case to achive the same @Nic Laforge.

Comment: @MITHU please see my answer

Comment: I agree. The issue seems to be that the data you wish to scrape is being rendered serverside. This means that plains old requests module won't cut it. The reason is that requests works by grabbing data from a webpage as soon as it loads in. It doesn't grab any data after it loads. The data you wish to scrape is being added to the page after it initially was loaded (being rendered by JS or a backend language). So, you need a tool that is able to grab data from a page AFTER it has been loaded. So yes, I'm afraid that selenium is the best and easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote

import requests


def get_contact_html(email: str):
    encoded = quote('o=\"University of Notre Dame\", '
                    'st=Indiana, '
                    'c=US?displayName,edupersonaffiliation,ndTitle,ndDepartment,postalAddress,telephoneNumber,mail,searchGuide,labeledURI,'
                    'uid?'
                    'sub?'
                    f'(&(ndMail=*{email}*))')
    data = {
        "ldapurl": f'LDAP://directory.nd.edu:389/{encoded}',
        "ldaphost": "directory.nd.edu",
        "ldapport": '389',
        "ldapbase": 'o="University of Notre Dame", st=Indiana, c=US',
        "ldapfilter": f'(&(ndMail=*{email}*))',
        "ldapheadattr": "displayname",
        "displayformat": "nd",
        "ldapmask": "",
        "ldapscope": "",
        "ldapsort": "",
        "ldapmailattr": "",
        "ldapurlattr": "",
        "ldapaltattr": "",
        "ldapjpgattr": "",
        "ldapdnattr": "",
    }
    res = requests.post('https://eds.nd.edu/cgi-bin/nd_ldap_search.pl',
                        data=data)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return res.text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = get_contact_html('africk2@nd.edu')
    print(html)
```

output:

```
...
Formal Name:
...
Aaron D Frick
...
```

this will give you the HTML for the page. 
The trick was converting encoded spaces `+` to real spaces   in `"ldapbase": 'o="University of Notre Dame", st=Indiana, c=US',` field and letting `requests` module to encode the value itself. Otherwise `+` signs get double encoded.

Comment: You can also get the same information by looking at the network tab of the post result url. Just need to refresh the page

Comment: Yeah, realized it once I started monitoring the popup page 